# erlang macro with double question marks

Tags: macros, erlang

I know that  a macro is defined [as follows](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html):

```
-define(Const, Replacement).
-define(Func(Var1,...,VarN), Replacement).
```

But how does this code with double question marks meam, and how should I understand it?

```
-define(Assign(Var,Exp), Var=Exp, io:format("~s = ~s -> ~p~n", [??Var, ??Exp, Var] )).

start() ->
   ?Assign(X, lists:sum([1, 2, 3])).
```

Its output reads:

```
X = lists : sum ( [ 1 , 2 , 3 ] ) -> 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching, I find it.
[Stringifying Macro Arguments](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-6.0/doc/reference_manual/macros.html)

```
The construction ??Arg, where Arg is a macro argument, 
will be expanded to a string containing the tokens of the argument. 
This is similar to the #arg stringifying construction in C.

The feature was added in Erlang 5.0/OTP R7.
```